# Files directory empty

Tags: wordpress, extension, filesystem

I recently installed Civi on WordPress 4.8. Upon wanting to manually upload an extension to the extension directory, I saw that the "files" directory is empty.

In the installation guide it said to create a files folder within /plugins/files.

I see the resource URL for extensions is where this should be. I've not seen this happen on other installs of mine, so wondering if others have seen this.

Also, I have downloaded the native extensions and they are working; where are those located?

Answer (score 1):

You can find where extensions are located by looking under

Administer>System Settings>Directories

The entry most likely has path variable such as [civicrm.files]. To find this location click on the "?" next to the following line in the info box on the top of the screen.

"You may configure these upload directories using absolute paths or path variables."

If you have installed Version 4.7 of CiviCRM the path to the extension folder is most likely: [wordpress folder]/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext